# how to click action link menu option in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, actionlink, client-side-scripting

I have a action link which is given below

```
<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Suppliers New", "SupplierPartialViewNew", "Supplier", null, new { @class = "navLinks", id = "ManageSuppliersNew" })</li>
</ul>
```

How do I click on above menu option in JavaScript. I am trying to click it forcefully (click in JavaScript when page load)

I am trying this but It is not working. May I am doing some mistake

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //debugger;
        alert("You reached here");
        $('#ManageSuppliersNew').click(function () { /* bla */ });
    </script>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in a ready handler: `$(function() {
    // your code here
});`

Comment: To click it you do `$('#ManageSuppliersNew').click()` - `.click(function() { ...` is a *click handler* that runs *when* you click it.   Both need to be in doc.ready (as above comment) or your script at the end of the body

Comment: The html may be not yet rendered. Try leave your script in the end of the body. Or use $(document).ready to wrap your code.